# How to pass user image from Tablecell to Viewcontroller on firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, segue, tablecell

I was only able to pass user name labels from table cell to another Viewcontroller but not the user image. I tried using prepare for segue function as you can see in my code below. thanks

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage

class MainVc: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {




@IBOutlet weak var tableview2: UITableView!
var user = [User]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    retrieveUsers()


}

func retrieveUsers() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        let users = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]
        self.user.removeAll()
        for (_, value) in users {
            if let uid = value["uid"] as? String {
                if uid != Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid {
                    let userToShow = User()
                    if let fullName = value["full name"] as? String,let businessType = value["Business Type"] as? String, let imagePath = value["urlToImage"] as? String {

                        userToShow.fullName = fullName
                        userToShow.businessType = businessType

                        userToShow.imagePath = imagePath
                        userToShow.userID = uid

                        self.user.append(userToShow)


                    }

                }



            }



        }


        self.tableview2.reloadData()
    })

    ref.removeAllObservers()

}




 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {



    let upcoming: ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController

    let indexPath = self.tableview2.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    let titleString = self.user[indexPath.row].fullName


    let imageView = self.user[indexPath.row].imagePath! // i tried using this to transfer the image  from tableview to viewcontroller but its not working 

    upcoming.imageView = imageView

    upcoming.titleString = titleString


    self.tableview2.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)



}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return user.count ?? 0
}



func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableview2.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell


    cell.userNameLbl.text = self.user[indexPath.row].fullName
     cell.businessTypeLbl.text = self.user[indexPath.row].businessType

    cell.userID = self.user[indexPath.row].userID
    cell.userImage.downloadImage(from: self.user[indexPath.row].imagePath!)

    return cell
}    
}   

extension UIImageView {

    func downloadImage(from imgURL: String!) {
        let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: imgURL)!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }


    }
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var testLbl: UILabel!

var titleString: String!
var imageView: String!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

     self.testLbl.text = self.titleString
     self.profileImage.image = UIImage(named: imageView!)



}
```

import UIKit

class User: NSObject {

```
var userID: String!
var fullName: String!
var imagePath: String!
var businessType: String!
```

}

Comment: User3700449 aceess image name from array just like string name.ex-: let imageString = self.user[indexPath.row].imageName and, 
upcoming. profileImage= imageString.you can't directly pass image you need to pass image name and then render on second controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self.profileImage.self.downloadImage(from: imageString)

Answer (score 0):

You can define UIImage or image name property in your `ViewController` and access it from your `MainVc`. I have passed image name below.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

     @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!

     @IBOutlet weak var testLbl: UILabel!

     var titleString: String!
     var yourImageName:String!
     override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

     self.testLbl.text = self.titleString
     self.imageview.image = UIImage(named:yourImageName)
}
```

and pass image Name in your prepare for segue as

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let upcoming: ViewController = segue.destination as! ViewController
    let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let titleString = self.user[indexPath.row].fullName
    let imageName = self.user[indexPath.row].imagename // access image name from user array
    upcoming.titleString = titleString
    upcoming.yourImageName = imageName

    // here i want to pass user image as welH from cell to the viewcontroller
    self.tableview.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
 }
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!

Comment: i tried it, it didn't work, it takes me to the other viewcontroller but it doesn't pass any image,  i dunno why

Comment: i dont get any error it runs ok. its just that the picture from the tablecell  doesnt appear in the other viewcontroller when i segue. i get a white picture.

Comment: Check the image name if its correct. If url do check in browser.